# Error channel for executor channel

Tags: spring-integration

I am using an executor channel since I want to switch threads to finish the transaction at this point. The only other way to do this is a poller and I think the executor channel is a much nicer solution. The only problem is that I cannot find a way to define an error channel for this dispatcher. Errors are always published on the global errorChannel.

Here is my config:

```
<task:executor id="routingExec" pool-size="10"/>

<int:channel id="baseFlow.route">
    <int:dispatcher failover="false" task-executor="routingExec"/>
</int:channel>
```

And I want to have something like this (like in the poller):

```
<task:executor id="routingExec" pool-size="10"/>

<int:channel id="baseFlow.route">
    <int:dispatcher error-channel="myErrorChannel" failover="false" task-executor="routingExec"/>
</int:channel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors are handled in the `ExecutorChannel` via `ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor`:

```
if (!(this.executor instanceof ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor)) {
    ErrorHandler errorHandler = new MessagePublishingErrorHandler(
            new BeanFactoryChannelResolver(this.getBeanFactory()));
    this.executor = new ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor(this.executor, errorHandler);
}
```

Where `defaultErrorChannel` is really like `IntegrationContextUtils.ERROR_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME`.

So, to use your own channel for error from that `ExecutorChannel`, you should use `errorChannel` header for each message to send, or just inject your own `ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor` with `MessagePublishingErrorHandler` and `defaultErrorChannel` configured to your expectations.